# cannot pass data to a JSON file using node.js file-system & browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, filesystems, browserify

I am currently attempting to convert incoming input data from a form to data that can be stored within a JSON file, I am basically trying my hand at having a form without a back-end to store data.

I am using Node.JS module "fs" || "file-system"

I am also using Browserify for bundling as I am aware in order to use "require('fs')" it would need to be in a node environment and need to use a bundler to make it work in browser which is what I need.

I have built a test environment to prior to testing with the actual form by creating a button, once clicked pushes data from an object within my main.js file to my test.JSON file using node.js file-system but I am running into a current error of:

```
bundle.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.submit (bundle.js:16)
```

Also I am not seeing any source code being bundled into my bundle.js file after calling

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

I tested this with a simple ramda function to see how browserify should embed code and I do not get the same result when using file-system.

index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>         
    body {
        background-color: #636363;
    }
    section {
        height: 80vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    div {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }

    button {
        padding: 40px;
        font-size: 2rem;
        width: 150px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div>
                <button>Add to JSON</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");
let fs = require('fs');

function submit() {

let obj = {
   table: []
};

fs.writeFile('test.json', 'utf8');

fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
    obj = JSON.parse(data); 
    obj.table.push({id: 2, square:3}); 
    json = JSON.stringify(obj); 
    fs.writeFile('test.json', 'utf8'); 

}

button.addEventListener("click", submit);
```

bundle.js

```
(function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
const button = document.querySelector("button");
let fs = require('fs');

function submit() {

let obj = {
   table: []
};

fs.writeFile('test.json', 'utf8');

fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    obj.table.push({id: 2, square:3});
    json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    fs.writeFile('test.json', 'utf8');
}});

}

button.addEventListener("click", submit);

},{"fs":1}]},{},[2]);
```

Comment: Did you find any alternative to it? I searched for it and it is not possible in browserify.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `fs` to write files, you can only use it to read files and that is only done to a certain extent with Browserify. That code may work in Node, but it won't work in the browser because there is no file system to write the files to.